# Three.js FirstPersonControls camera rotation jumps back after GSAP tween / restart controls

Tags: three.js, gsap

Trying to rotate camera after mousedown on raycaster with slerp. But after the animation when i turn the control back on, the camera jumps back to its previous rotation. Updating controls seems not to solve this. What i'm missing here?

```
function mousedown( event ) {
    
  mouse.x = ( event.clientX / windowWidth ) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / windowHeight ) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
  intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( targets );

  if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

    // stop controls
    controls.enabled = false;

    var targetOrientation = intersects[0].object.quaternion.normalize();
    gsap.to({}, 1, { 
      onUpdate: function() {
        controls.update();
        //camera.lookAt( intersects[0].object.position );
        camera.quaternion.slerp( targetOrientation , this.progress() );
      },
      onComplete: function() {
        controls.update();
        //camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ) );

        // restart controls
        controls.enabled = true;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pixeldino/s30pbzj7/152/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FirstPersonControls` maintains an internal state of the camera's orientation. By using `camera.quaternion.slerp()` this state gets out of sync.

You can solve this by using `FirstPersonControls.lookAt()` at the end of your animation. In this way, the internal state will be updated by forcing the controls to look at the destination point.

https://jsfiddle.net/fnw8643a/